# win32com module not found

Tags: python-3.x, win32com

I am trying to get pyttsx3 up and running on my computer. I did *pip install pyttsx3* and *pip install pypiwin32* I can see both of them in my python directory.

I type this code in to test it:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I will speak this text")
engine.runAndWait()
```

This is what comes out:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3__init__.py", line 44, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\weakref.py", line 131, in **getitem**
    o = self.datakey
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Danny\Desktop\python text to speech.py", line 9, in 
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
  File "C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3__init__.py", line 46, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 52, in **init**
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 77, in **init**
    self._driver = self._module.buildDriver(weakref.proxy(self))
  File "C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 22, in buildDriver
    return SAPI5Driver(proxy)
  File "C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 41, in **init**
    self.setProperty('voice', self.getProperty('voice'))
  File "C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 83, in setProperty
    self._tts.Voice = token
  File "C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 549, in **setattr**
    self.*oleobj*.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)

I tried the same thing on another computer that already had both installed, and got the same output. Any idea what is going on with the win32com? I have no experience with it and am pretty lost. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I found the answer looking at other problems that were related to the win32com module. Basically what you need to do is navigate to your python scripts folder (in my case: *C:\Users\Danny\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts*) and run *pywin32_postinstall*. Upon running that script, it works perfectly!

Cheers!