# I am getting a "member not found" error with pyttsx3 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-2017, pyttsx

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and creating a Python application. I am getting a "member not found" error with pyttsx3 in python. The method gets called successfully the first few times, then the error gets called, and I am unable to call the method further. Can anyone please help?

I have tried updating the pyttsx3 module in both the Python 3.6 (64-bit) and Python 3.7 (32-bit) environments.

I have also tried the answer in the question at "[win32com module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49563327/win32com-module-not-found)". I am still getting the error

```
def Say(text):
    try:
        speechEngine = pyttsx3.init()
        speechEngine.setProperty('rate', 150)
        print("{0} | Lola: {1}".format(TimeOfDay(), text))
        speechEngine.say(text)
        speechEngine.runAndWait()
        logging.info("Spoken words ({0})".format(text))
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
        print("{0} | Lola: {1}".format(TimeOfDay(),"I have come across an error in my code. See the log for details"))
```

The expected result is that it should speak the output text. However, I get the following error:

I get the following error:

```
Exception occurred
 Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 44, in init
     eng = _activeEngines[driverName]

   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
     o = self.data[key]()

  KeyError: None
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "C:\Users\IllyS\OneDrive\Programming\My Programs\GitHub\Lola-Mark-II\Lola\Lola.py", line 23, in Say  
     speechEngine = pyttsx3.init()  

   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 46, in init  
     eng = Engine(driverName, debug)  

   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 52, in __init__  
     self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)

   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 77, in __init__
     self._driver = self._module.buildDriver(weakref.proxy(self))  

   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 22, in buildDriver  
     return SAPI5Driver(proxy)  

   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 41, in __init__  
     self.setProperty('voice', self.getProperty('voice'))  

   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 72, in getProperty  
     return self._tts.Voice.Id  

   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 474, in __getattr__  
     return self._ApplyTypes_(*args)  

   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 467, in _ApplyTypes_  
     self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),
     pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, 'Member not found.', None, 0, -2147201001), None)
```

Comment: Consider formatting your exceptions (I know it is a pain!) the same way you did your code.  It will make your question more readable and thus more likely to get an answer.

Comment: I am new to Python and exceptions. Would you be able to guide me in the right direction as to good formatting? Thanks

Comment: I think your Python formatting was fine.  It was the exceptions themselves that were hard to read.  I did the first one for you as an example

Comment: I have done it, thank you for your help. Is that any better?

Comment: Try to run this code without the try/except, that could help making the exception clearer

Comment: I fixed the error. It was because I was calling "speechEngine = pyttsx3.init()"
and "speechEngine.setProperty('rate', 150)" over and over again in the method. I moved this to outside and it worked. Currently not seeing the error after any amount of time. Will see how it goes...........

Comment: You should post that as an answer (as it is :) and not as a comment.  Then you can accept it - though I think you have to wait a day....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error. It was because I was calling `speechEngine = pyttsx3.init()` and `speechEngine.setProperty('rate', 150)` over and over again in the method (as I had a **while** loop calling this method). I moved them to outside and it worked. Currently not seeing the error after any amount of time. Will see how it goes.....