# Pyttsx3 works on 32bit-Python but not on 64bit-Python

Tags: python, windows, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

#### Situation

I am using the pyttsx3 module for my Alexa-like project. The source code I wrote all worked fine on my own PC, but now I am trying to get this thing to work on a Pi.

- System : Raspberry Pi 4GB (64-bit quad-core processor)
- OS : Windows 10 Pro [from the WoR project](https://www.worproject.ml/)
- Python version : 3.9.1 (64bit) & 3.6.0 (32bit)

#### Source code:

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()
nl_voice_id = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\MSTTS_V110_nlNL_Frank" # Dutch Voice..
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', nl_voice_id)

def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

talk('test')
```

Nothing special but when I run this code on a 64-bit based Python version I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\weakref.py", line 134, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 3, in <module>
    from comtypes.gen import SpeechLib  # comtypes
ImportError: cannot import name 'SpeechLib' from 'comtypes.gen' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\user\user-master\userv2\user\Static\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 6, in <module>
    engine = comtypes.client.CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 238, in CreateObject
    obj = comtypes.CoCreateInstance(clsid, clsctx=clsctx, interface=interface)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 1219, in CoCreateInstance
    _ole32.CoCreateInstance(byref(clsid), punkouter, clsctx, byref(iid), byref(p))
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 1010, in GetResult
OSError: [WinError -2147024703] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

What caught my eye was the last line: `OSError: [WinError -2147024703] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`

So I tried running the exact same program with a 32bit Python version. This worked. But I need this to work on 64bit because I have some other modules installed in my real program that else won't work properly.

- I already have pypiwin32 installed.
- I already have pywin32 installed.

I also tried to uninstall pytts3x and install the 2.71 version with `pip install pyttsx3==2.71`, this gave me a pywintypes_com error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\Kali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\weakref.py", line 134, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: 'sapi5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Kali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 81, in _GetGoodDispatch
        IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
    pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221021, 'Operation unavailable', None, None)
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Kali\Documents\Kali\Kali-master\Kaliv2\Kali\Static\test.py", line 3, in <module>
        engine = pyttsx3.init("sapi5")
      File "C:\Users\Kali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
        eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
      File "C:\Users\Kali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
        self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
      File "C:\Users\Kali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 52, in __init__
        self._driver = self._module.buildDriver(weakref.proxy(self))
      File "C:\Users\Kali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 23, in buildDriver
        return SAPI5Driver(proxy)
      File "C:\Users\Kali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 28, in __init__
        self._tts = win32com.client.Dispatch('SAPI.SPVoice')
      File "C:\Users\Kali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
        dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
      File "C:\Users\Kali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 98, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
        return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
      File "C:\Users\Kali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 83, in _GetGoodDispatch
        IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
    pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024703, 'OLE error 0x800700c1', None, None)
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49563327/win32com-module-not-found?rq=1) to solve this pywintypes error, but no luck.

What more can I try?

#### Edit:

When I installed Raspbian (32bit) on the Pi, I, unfortunately, got the same error. I think Pyttsx3 is a really good module but not for the Pi. So I did some research to find another Text-to-Speech (TTS) module for Python. I came across [gTTS](https://pypi.org/project/gTTS/), which is also a great module and easy to integrate. It uses Google translate, so you can choose from each Google Translate language.

This is my workaround for now. If anyone has an answer to why pyttsx3 ain't working on a Pi, let me know. Although gTTS is great, I like Sapi5 more.